# Regexp to remove text before any p tags

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, strip-tags

I have an HTML fragment in a string in PHP. It is some css text followed by one or more p-tag enclosed paragraphs.

```
 .cs2E86D3A6{text-align:center; blarblarblar}<p>First paragraph. Keep this text</p><p>Second paragraph. Keep this text</p><p>Last paragraph.</p>
```

(It happens to be the outcome of strip_tags.)
I want to remove any rubbish text before `<p>First paragraph`, so what's remaining are those in p tags.

I tried

```
preg_replace('@^.*(?=<p>)@','', $mystring)
```

but it gives me only the last `<p>Last paragraph</p>`.

Would tell teach me a regexp that does the task.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/477127 TL:DR, use a proper DOM-aware parser

Comment: Fully respect that advice. My use case is handling of HTML mechanically converted from Word (which you may think a stupid motive to start with), and I am just sanitizing the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *lazy-repeat* any character until you get to the first `<p>`. Your `.*` is *greedy*, which means it'll match as many characters as it can, including `<p>`s, as long as there is a `<p>` that follows. So, it'll currently match up until the last `<p>` in the string. Put `?` after `*` or `+` to make the repetition lazy instead of greedy:

```
$orig = '.cs2E86D3A6{text-align:center; blarblarblar}<p>First paragraph. Keep this text</p><p>Second paragraph. Keep this text</p><p>Last paragraph.</p>';
print(preg_replace('@^.*?(?=<p>)@','', $orig))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use function strstr

```
strstr($mystring, '<p>');
```

It returns everything from start of the `'<p>'` to the end of the string.

[strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) Documentation

Comment: Thank you. It works as you advised and it is a simple and elegant solution.